# Changed phone number, forgot password, can't get in to Azure :(

Tags: azure

I have an Azure/O365 subscription but unfortunately I changed  my phone number and forgotten my password (at the same time!).

Now I can't reset my account password because it needs to send a txt but this has my old number only. :(

Is t here any way to let Microsoft know so that they could cancel my account?

Thanks

Comment: Try [opening a support ticket](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?wf=0&tenant=ClassicCommercial&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&locale=en-us&supportreion=en-us&pesid=15470&ccsid=635748318215000435)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just call support?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/getsupport?wf=0&tenant=ClassicCommercial&oaspworkflow=start_1.0.0.0&locale=en-us&supportregion=en-us&pesid=15470&ccsid=635748318280879226